# Having issues with counting dicts in python

Tags: python

I am having an issue with my code. I am trying to print out in numerical order the folder's name while taking in information from that folder's `Report.csv` file.

```
red = []
black = []
orange = []

for x in dirs:
    if x[0:3] == "red":
        red.append(x)     
    elif x[0:5] == "black":
        black.append(x)
    elif x[0:6] == "orange":
        orange.append(x)

for x in red:
    print(f"{x}:")
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(x + "/Report.csv")
        df_filter= df[['Start','ID','Name',"Type", "Status", "Info"]]
        testFilter = df_filter[(df_filter.Type == 'Test')]
        if testFilter['Status'].str.contains('Fail').any():
            fullFinalTable= testFilter[['Start','ID','Name', "Info"]]
            print(fullFinalTable)
        else:
            print("No errors.")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File does not exist")
```

When doing `print(f"{x}:")` I will get the following output

```
red1
red10
red11
.
.
.
red19
red2
red20
red21
.
.
.
```

However, I am trying to make sure it is in numerical order `(red1, red2, red3...red10, red11, etc)`. I have tried to convert x into a `float` and an `integer`, however no luck.

Comment: Take a look at the natsort library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
red_order = [int(x.replace('red','')) for x in red]
red_order.sort()
red = ['red'+str(x) for x in red_order]
```

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like you might be better off removing your color prefixes and then just storing the numbers. If you do that, then you can cast to `int` and then sort numerically.

```py
red = []
for x in dirs:
   if x.startswith('red'): # startswith is just easier to read, for me.
       red.append(int(x[3:])) # store only the number part, and store it as an integer.
                              # That way it will be sorted numerically by `sorted` below.

# Just sorting inline because why not? It looks cleaner to me.
for x in sorted(red):
    full_name = 'red' + str(x)

    print(f"{x}:")

    # Do what you were doing before.
```

If you need something a bit more verbose, then I would recommend the [`natsort` library.](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) It has a lot of different options which address the less intuitive sorting problems in programming. This is a basic example which addresses your problem directly:

```py
>>> from natsorted import natsorted
>>> a = ['version-1.9', 'version-2.0', 'version-1.11', 'version-1.10']
>>> natsorted(a)
['version-1.9', 'version-1.10', 'version-1.11', 'version-2.0']
```

And here is their example for `humansorted`

```
>>> a = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'apple', 'banana']
>>> natsorted(a)
['Apple', 'Banana', 'apple', 'banana']
>>> humansorted(a)
['apple', 'Apple', 'banana', 'Banana']
```